# PendingIntent action on android widget updates variable after execution instead of before?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to create a simple widget in Android to set an alarm for one hour after pressing a button.

```
    Integer plusOneHour = getCurrentHour() + 1;
    Integer carryTheMinutes = getCurrentMinutes();
    Intent setAlarm1Hour = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    setAlarm1Hour.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, plusOneHour);
    setAlarm1Hour.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, carryTheMinutes);

    PendingIntent pendingButton1Intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, setAlarm1Hour, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT isn't working as I expect it to, it creates an alarm with the previous integer values that were cached and then updates them, so I don't get the right alarm time set unless I delete the alarm and press the button again. What is the right approach here?

Comment: The extras you're attaching there are created when that code runs, not when the `Button` is clicked. If you want to schedule from the click event, then you should instead create a `PendingIntent` that targets a component in your app - e.g., `getBroadcast()` for a `BroadcastReceiver` - from which you can figure the correct time an hour ahead, and then start the `ACTION_SET_ALARM` `Intent` directly.

Comment: Thanks Mike, unfortunately I'm not sure if I fully understand how to use getBroadcast(). I would want to make a new public class that extends BroadcastReceiver and then define the Intent in there and call it with context.startActivity(setAlarm1Hour)?

Comment: Got it! I was able to use getBroadcast without extending BroadcastReceiver by using an if statement in onReceive to evaluate the action. I also had to declare the action in my receiver XML for it to work.